# Wrapping Product Review Form in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: product, layout, blocks, review

I'm trying to get `review/form.phtml`, and wrap it inside a Bootstrap dialog box inside `catalog/product/tabs/review_form.phtml`. I got the `review/form.phtml` from base/default.

The `catalog/product/tabs/review_form.phtml` looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <h3>Write a Review</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <?php $this->getChildHtml('review_form'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, my Product View `catalog.xml` layout includes this block:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
  <block type="review/form" name="tab_review_form" template="catalog/product/view/tabs/review_form.phtml">
    <block type="review/observer" name="review_form" template="review/form.phtml" />
  </block>
</reference>
```

The `review/form.phtml` does not display. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons that may cause th issue.

1. Block with name `review_form` lacks with `as` property. `as` property is block alias name which will later use in phtml file to call a particular block. You called this block in `review_form.phtml` as like this

   ```
    <?php $this->getChildHtml('review_form'); ?>
   ```

Here the **value used in `getChildHtml()` function should be alias name of block and not the name of the block**. So update your layout like this.

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
  <block type="review/form" name="tab_review_form" template="catalog/product/view/tabs/review_form.phtml">
    <block type="core/template" name="review_form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml" />
  </block>
</reference>
```

From your layout file your custom block type specified as `review/observer`. This would probably a mistake. Because `review` stands for the core module `Mage_Review` and it has no block class with name `Observer`. So juts make your block type to `core/template` that would work(as I shown above).

2. As @SanderMangel suggestion would be checked if you are using a custom module. you should ensure `review_form` block is defined inside your module. Suppose your custom module name is `Namespace_Module` and it lives inside `local` codePool, then it requires that this file to be defined.

FILE : `app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Observer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

You need to define `block` section inside your config.xml file .

File : `app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`

<[namespace_module]>
                  [Namespace]_[Module]_Block

and now change your custom block as like this in layout xml file.

```
 <block type="[namespace]_[module]/observer" name="review_form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml" />
```

[*This answer is a part of #mageStackDay. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/*]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `review/observer` is not core Magento so it can't find the block and silently fails. The `Mage_Review` extensions block class for the form is `review/form`, please try and add that one

Comment: I have provided a better answer below. :-)